# How Ruby implements Enumerator#next method?

Tags: ruby

```
class MyString
  include Enumerable
  def initialize(n)
    @num = n
  end
  def each
    i = 0
    while i < @num
      yield "#{i} within while"
      puts "After yield #{i}"
      i += 1
    end
  end
end

s = MyString.new(10)
a = s.to_enum
puts "first"
puts a.next
puts "second"
puts  a.next
```

My ruby version is 2.2.5, and outputs of codes are

> first
>   0 within while
>   second
>   After yield 0
>   1 within while

I think the execution flow is `first a.next->s.each->while->yield->second a.next->jump into while loop`
My question is how Enumerator#next method is implemented?

I probably know there are break in block yield invoked, which cause `yield->second a.next`; however, I don't understand how second a.next can jump back into a while loop.

Comment: I guess what confuse you is the `yield` keyword, not how `next` is implemented.

Comment: @halfelf: I believe it is very much about `Enumerator`: it was not possible in 1.8, before fibers were introduced. Plain `yield` works only with blocks, and there is no blocks in OP's code. Which means the block that catches the `tield` is inside `Enumerator`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand how second a.next can jump back into a while loop.

<strike>Magic.</strike> `Enumerator`'s (and `Fiber`'s) superpowers.

These two classes were introduced in Ruby 1.9, and share many similarities; in particular, they allow you to do manual co-operative green-threading.

Let's look at fibers first, as they are more basic:

```
f = Fiber.new do
  puts "A"
  Fiber.yield 1
  puts "B"
  Fiber.yield 2
  puts "C"
end

puts "First"    # First
puts f.resume   # A
                # 1
puts "Second"   # Second
puts f.resume   # B
                # 2
puts "End"      # End
f.resume        # C
f.resume        # FiberError: dead fiber called
```

Basically, a fiber is like a thread, but it will pause whenever it yields by `Fiber.yield`, and resume whenever it is resumed by `Fiber#resume`. It is implemented in C as basic capability of *Ruby*, so as a student of Ruby (as opposed to student of Ruby *interpreter*) you don't need to know how it works, just that it does (just like you need to know `IO#read` will read a file, but not necessarily how it is implemented in C).

`Enumerator` is almost the same concept, but adapted for iteration (whereas `Fiber` is more multi-purpose). In fact, we can write the above almost exactly word-for-word the same with an `Enumerator`:

```
e = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
  puts "A"
  yielder.yield 1
  puts "B"
  yielder.yield 2
  puts "C"
end

puts "First"    # First
puts e.next     # A
                # 1
puts "Second"   # Second
puts e.next     # B
                # 2
puts "End"      # End
e.next          # C
                # StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

Comment: "Basically, a fiber is like a thread" – I would say it's more like a semi-coroutine than like a thread.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: AFAIK, fibers are not *like* semi-coroutines, they *are* semi-coroutines. However, many people know about threads, while semi-coroutines are not that widely known.